# How to call Service class function?

Tags: laravel

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ATransaction;
use App\Service\ATransactionServices;

class TransactionController extends Controller {  

   public function ATransaction(Request $request, ATransactionServices $ATransaction){

        try {
            $validated_request = $this->validateRequest($request);
         } catch (ValidationException $exception) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($exception->errors());
        }
```

How to call my service class function to replace into

```
$validated_request = $this->validateRequest($request);
```

Can someone show me the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can traits concepts or can directly use DI ( dependency Injection ) to implement service into this class.

For traits, you can check [How to create traits in Laravel](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-traits-how-to-create-trait-in-laravelexample.html)

And if you want to use [Dependency Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container) then do something like:

```
public function __construct(ATransactionServices $aTransactionServices) 
{
    $this->aTransactionServices = $aTransactionServices;
}
```

Then inside the method you can directly use the service methods:

```
$this->aTransactionServices->methodName();
```

If you want to use method inside the `try` and `catch` than simplest way is to add them in controller.

```
class TransactionController extends Controller { 
        //This will help in directly injecting the service into the container
                public function __construct(ATransactionServices $aTransactionServices) 
            {
              $this->aTransactionServices = $aTransactionServices;
            }
        //Otherwise you can create a custom request to handle validations on the request level
            public function ATransaction(Request $request){
        
                try {
                    $validated_request = $this->aTransactionServices->validateRequest($request);
        //Here you can setup the validation mechanism like custom status based validation e.g. $validated_request['status'] which can be true or false otherwise use validator instance to use $validated_request->fails() to check
        if($validated_request->fails()) {
        //Here pass the data and you can handle on catch how you want to send response
        throw new Exception('Exception details or validator instance');
    
    }       
     } catch (Exception $exception) {
                return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($exception->errors());
            }
    
    }
```

But if your only purpose is to handle the validations than you can use custom request in laravel for validations handling: [Custom Request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests)

Hope this works for you and resolves your issue.
have a great day.

Comment: Im not really understand like how to combine with my try catch? Can you teach me please

Comment: Try and catch with always will be in the parent where the method is being called from.

Answer (score -1):

```
$validated_request = $ATransaction->validateRequest($request);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.